# NodeJs/Express tries to GET when I do a POST

Tags: node.js, post, express, get

```
pap.post('/API/Phone/Say', ApiPhone.Say);

exports.Say = function(req, res, next)
{

 }, function()
 {

 });

//Render the TwiML document using "toString"
res.writeHead(200,
{
      'Content-Type':'text/xml'
});

res.end(resp.toString());

};

http://localhost:8080/api/Phone/Say
Cannot GET /api/Phone/Say
```

PostMan gives me correct respone

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>

</Response>
```

Comment: What is `pap`? If it's Express, you're using the wrong module, Express is not for issuing requests, you should use `request` for example.

Comment: pap is express. If it is the wrong module how come postman renders the xml correctly

Comment: Postman is a *client*, express is not, request is the equivalent of Postman. How do you get the **Cannot GET /api/Phone/Say** error? if it's when you're accessing the url in your browser, it's normal, a browser does a GET request by default. Also, is that your complete code?

Comment: Thanks. Sorry for wasting your time. The twilio api was saying it was making a get call not a post when it was a different error altogether.